# Como autenticar o meu formulário com certificado Word em C#?

Tags: c#

Sou novo nesta área, gostaria de apenas escrever o nome dos alunos no formulário e ele gera já o certificado word de acordo ao modelo que temos na instituição. OBS: Mas gostaria um codigo c# que facilita-se para quando eu mudar o software de pc, ele ainda reconhecesse o caminho do documento modelo. pleas!

Comment: Queira consultar a [help] e respectivos links para um melhor entendimento da finalidade das perguntas e respostas do site.